# Marketing cloud SAP

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloud, sap

I will be migrating all of my domains away from their current .com addresses and to the new TLD .XXXX

I have already configured an SAP in Salesforce on the old .COM domain for a child BU in Enterprise 2.0

Can I resubmit / update the SAP (paid / free?) for my existing child BU and future ones? Are there any further issues I need to make sure I am considering for doing this to active brands?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have applied SAP to one of your BUs, using the SAP form, you can just raise a support case, asking for the SAP to be applied to remaining BUs.

Answer (score 0):

We now also have the option to copy the SAP domain from the Enterprise account (parent account) to child business units from the UI itself.
You can navigate to the Parent MID -> Email Studio -> Admin -> From Address Management , select the SAP domain and you get an option to copy that SAP domain to child BUs.